# What are the exact weapon stats in Deus Ex: Invisible War?

Tags: deus-ex-invisible-war

In Deus Ex: Invisible War, the exact weapon stats are not shown anywhere in-game. You can certainly make some conclusions on your own: a shotgun is obviously nigh-deadly at close distances, a headshot from a sniper rifle is deadly, a typical enemy requires 2 fully-ticked shots from a Boltcaster, etc.

But when you encounter a special weapon, you don't know if it actually has anything special to it.